# Show keyboard when you click autocompletetextview android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, autocompletetextview

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` inside a `LinearLayout`. Once the app is open, the keyboard is shown but when the back button is clicked and the keyboard is reopened by clicking on the `AutoCompleteTextView`, nothing happens. I think it´s something about focus. Here is my XML

**EDIT**

```
<TabHost
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
                        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/bt"
                        android:text="@string/Buscar"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/tv1"
                        android:text="@+id/text1"/>
                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/btnmapa"
                        android:text="@string/mapa"/>
                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Show full XML layout file.

Comment: I have tried your code, Running absolutely fine. May be there is some other issue. Post your complete XML

Comment: The LinearLayout is part of a TabHost with 3 tabs, could it be something about it?